# "cat /proc/net/dev" and "ip -s link" show different statistics. Which one is lying?

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I notice that `/proc/net/dev` says eth3 has 1753 `drop`s. `ip -s link` shows 0 `dropped`. Why is there a difference? Where is the different data coming from? Which one is correct?

I've stripped the out extra data.

```
# uname -a
Linux example09 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 22 17:26:33 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.4 (squeeze)
Release:        6.0.4
Codename:       squeeze

# cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
  eth3:1258629839430 12545003042    0 1753    0     0          0  10594858 6666255952912 10026428444    0    0    0     0       0          0

# ip -s link
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:17:96:0b:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    244248462  3955476484 0       0       0       10595400
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    683632524  1436809416 0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Same here. It looks like a 32-bit integer rollover in the userspace programs (`ifconfig` does the same thing here) but according to `bc`, `1258629839430%(2^32)` is `204421702` not 244248462, so I'm not sure that's it (unless you ran `ip` ~40MB later)

Comment: @DerfK Yes, about 40MB sounds right. Was just a few seconds, but it's a busy server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a Squeeze machine, trust `/proc/net/dev`. It's a more straightforward and reliable way of looking at the same data.

For the particular case of the dropped count, I can't explain the exact issue, but I can observe it on other Squeeze boxes. If I cared, I would report it as a bug to Debian (and suggest someone does and reports back here).

Both take the number from the `tx_dropped` field of `net_device_stats`. In `/proc/net/dev`, the line is generated by `dev_seq_printf_stats` from `net/core/dev.c`.

`ip` goes, as usual, through netlink, and more precisely for network device statistics, rtnetlink. The structure passed to userspace, `rtnl_link_stats`.

The native structure uses `unsigned long`s, `rtnetlink` uses `__u32`, an more or less implicit conversion is done in `copy_rtnl_link_stats`.

It's pretty easy to catch the 32-bit version is being used from the beginning of the structure, rx_packets: whilst `/proc/net/dev` shows 1258629839430, `ip` shows 244248462, which corresponds roughly to the last 32 bits (plus a few more bytes between commands); same thing with the packet count.

Here's the number crunching for those 2 first fields:

```
% echo '1258629839430 % (2^32)'|bc; echo 244248462
204421702
244248462
% echo '12545003042 % (2^32)'|bc; echo 3955476484 
3955068450
3955476484
```

Things got better around the introduction of `IFLA_STATS64`:

- in the kernel (from commit 10708f37ae729baba9b67bd134c3720709d4ae62, available upstream in v2.6.35 and later)
- in iproute2 (from commit 8864ac9dc5bd5ce049280337deb21191673a02d0, available upstream in v2.6.33-36 and later).

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

On most devices, */proc/net/dev* is read from hardware counters. Others stats are updated from the network stack in the device structures.

Drops are the more likely not to match as they can be made by the hardware: packet mac destination is neither device's nor multicast, and the device is not in promiscuous: hardware directly drops the packet, the stack will never know it existed.

Finally, you may be wondering why not sync them up or always use hardware stats? When stack drops a packet for any reason, it cannot update hardware counter, and for debugging it is useful to know you can find each to track down where the packet was drop.

Hope this helps